# How to pull added and modified files (untracked in current branch) from another branch in git?

Tags: git

Apologies if this is a duplicate, if so, please point me to the existing question; I've gone through so many other issues on SO regarding this, but every single one seems to just be a repost of some different scenario.

I have what feels like a simple scenario; I have a lot of changes on a development branch (B), and I want to commit/push a subset of those changes to a sidecar branch (A) in order to create a simplified pull request to merge them into master. Branch B has added files (untracked in A). I want to pull in both the modified files and new files from B. When I use `git checkout origin/B path/to/files/*`, it seems to only check out the modified files and none of the added files.

I've also gone down other rabbit holes in my time looking into this including `git restore` `git show` and a few other attempts to achieve what I'm trying to do. I know, since this feels like a very common use case, that I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

I originally included this in my post but it feels like a somewhat decent solution (at least in my case).

The steps that I used to achieve what I was looking for is as follows;

1. Checkout new branch `git checkout -B branchB`
2. Hard reset to master `git reset --hard origin/master`
3. Merge branchA onto branchB `git merge --no-ff --no-commit branchA`
4. Selectively add the changes that I want to merge into the branch, via a selective add `git add path/to/files`